# How to connect using Socket-IO-Swift on a self-signed certificate?

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, ssl, socket.io

I use the framework Socket.IO-cleint-swift. Below is the code for creating and connecting:

```
let socket = SocketIOClient.init(socketURL: URL(string: "https://ts4.steelsea.net:8080")!, config: [.log(true), .forcePolling(true),.secure(true),.selfSigned(true)])

        socket.on("connect") {data, ack in
            print("socket connected")
        }

        socket.on("currentAmount") {data, ack in
            if let cur = data[0] as? Double {
                socket.emitWithAck("canUpdate", cur).timingOut(after: 0) {data in
                    socket.emit("update", ["amount": cur + 2.50])
                }

                ack.with("Got your currentAmount", "dude")
            }
        }

        socket.connect()
```

Below is an error:

> ERROR SocketIOClient: The certificate for this server is invalid. You
>   might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be
>   “ts4.steelsea.net” which could put your confidential information at
>   risk.

I can not figure out how to confirm this certificate to me.

Comment: Go on https://ts4.steelsea.net:8080 and connect via simple browser and check validation of the certificate.Certificate is not valid. So error is expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is connected with insecure connection with the server. And that is why  `Socket.IO`  is sending you error.

If you would like to silent this error you can try to drop `secure(true)` and `selfSigned(true)` configs.

[image]

Comment: Hello, it is not working as of Swift5 and swift io iOS 15.2.0.